# Python state memory issue

Tags: python

I was coding some python (specifically behave tests) and got burned by some sort of state memory.

In some other module, we have a method that builds http headers:

```
def create_login_headers(headers={}, username=DEFAULT, password=DEFAULT)
```

in my behave step file, I have a method that accepts a header argument, but calls the above if one is not supplied:

```
def post(header=create_login_headers())
```

Normally I would take the default header by just invoking `post()`

For some of my testing, I needed to use a non-default user. So I called post like this:

```
post(header=create_login_headers("unprivileged_person","password"))
```

and it worked fine.

but the *next* call to `post`, which was invoked due to a setup in the `Background` section, started failing!

It became apparent that the headers were the culprit. I added this work of art to my Background section:

```
@given(u'default headers')
def step_impl(context):
    h = create_login_headers()
```

and the issue went away. (`h` is not a global variable). Perhaps the `{}` in the `create_login_headers` is the culprit.

Finally, my question - what part of python cached the old headers?  Does the function call in the `post` only do it once, and use the last value thereafter?

Comment: Never mind I see the brief mention of `python-behave` at the beginning now. Still, this question has little to nothing to do with that library. Let's keep our tags specific!~

Comment: I had no idea, @Two-BitAlchemist. That's why I was here looking for help.

Comment: Understood. Your question reads to me like a general Python question so I just thought the tag was confusing. I saw on rereading why you put it there. No worries, it's fixed now.